# Android Studio no carga ListView personalizado y no da ningun error

Tags: android-listview

he intentado hacer un ListView personalizado en Android Studio y al ejecutar la aplicación no tan solo no me carga nada, sino que no da ningun error. Lo único medio raro que sale es esto:

*W/r.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/r.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...*

**Clase desde la que se autoejecuta el listview**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lista;
String[][] datos = {
        {"Interstelar", "Christopher Nolan", "2:49", "9", "Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec." },
        {"Ex Machina", "Etiam Rhoncus", "1:32", "9", "Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec." },
};
int[] datosImg = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5, R.drawable.img6};
List<Adaptador> lst;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
    Adaptador a = new Adaptador(this, datos, datosImg);
    lista.setAdapter(a);
    
}
```

**Adaptador personalizado**

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

private static LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;    //Recoge elemento_lista.xml
Context context;
String[][] datos;
int datosImg[];

public Adaptador(Context context, String[][] datos, int[] datosImg) {
    this.context = context;
    this.datos = datos;
    this.datosImg = datosImg;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);
    TextView titulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbTitulo);
    TextView director = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbDirector);
    TextView duracion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbDuracion);
    ImageView imagen = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    RatingBar indicador = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbIndicador);

    titulo.setText(datos[position][0]); //position=fila, 0=columna
    director.setText(datos[position][1]);
    duracion.setText("Duración " + datos[position][2]);
    indicador.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(datos[position][3]));
    imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[position]);

    imagen.setTag(position);    //Etiqueta para saber que posición ha sido clickada
    imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Imagen " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            Intent visor = new Intent(context, Visor.class);
            visor.putExtra("IMG", datosImg[(Integer) view.getTag()]);
            context.startActivity(visor);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

¿Alguien sabe que está pasando?

[image: Resultado al ejecutar]

Answer (score 0):

La única solución que he encontrado es no extender de **BaseAdapter** la clase Adaptador. En su lugar he extendido de **ArrayAdapter** y parece funcionar bien.

```
public class Adaptador extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context context;
String rTitle[];
String rDescription[];
int rImages[];

public Adaptador(Context context, String[] rTitle, String[] rDescription, int[] rImages) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, R.id.lbTitle, rTitle);
    this.context = context;
    this.rTitle = rTitle;
    this.rDescription = rDescription;
    this.rImages = rImages;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    ImageView images = row.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
    TextView myTitle = row.findViewById(R.id.lbTitle);
    TextView mySubtitle = row.findViewById(R.id.lbSubTitle);

    images.setImageResource(rImages[position]);
    myTitle.setText(rTitle[position]);
    mySubtitle.setText(rDescription[position]);

    return row;
}
```